# Why do I have a FileNotFoundException on Eclipse when I'm no longer accessing the file?

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, filenotfoundexception

I'm using Eclipse for a project involving AWS SQS. I changed the way I passed in `AWSCredentials` so that I would be using environment variables instead of directly passing in a .properties file. Now having done that I get the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\test\resources\config\AWSCredentials.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.fleetcomplete.flex.AWSSimpleQueueServiceUtil.main(AWSSimpleQueueServiceUtil.java:102)
```

I've removed the file and changed the implementation so nowhere in my code anymore am I trying to access this file. Then why is there a `FileNotFoundException` when I've changed the implementation?

Comment: Without code, or at least AWSSimpleQueueServiceUtil.java:102, it's hard to go any further. Is Eclipse doing the compiling? Is it calling out to something else like Maven or Gradle to handle it?

Comment: we can't help you without sharing your code, we don't have superpower..